# Need a script that: Any files or folders added to a specific folder are auto copied to another folder then deleted from the first folder

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, directory, automation

So basically, someone adds files or directories to Folder A, those files or folders are automatically copied or even moved to Folder B, and removed from Folder A.

I'm new to Ubuntu and scripting in general. Some light on the subject or a link on how to generate something like this would be most helpful.

Btw, I'm Using Ubuntu Server 20.04

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/q/1201366/968501) might help. The command to copy directories is `cp -R source_directory destination_directory` and to move directories `mv source_directory destination_directory`

Comment: Why not have them add files to folder B in the first place and forget all about folder A?

Comment: The `inotify` command is where to start.