# Inotifywait apply regex pattern on changes in a file

Tags: command-line, server, bash, dpkg, inotify

Requirement: Alert if there is any package installed or removed in the ubuntu server.

For this requirement, I'm trying to use inotifywait to continuously monitor dpkg.log, if there are any changes using regex pattern for installed and removed package and alert based on that.

How can I take the modified content of a file which is being monitored by inotifywait to another file or store it in a variable, so that I can apply some regex and alert based on that?

Please help me how can I do this, or Is there any other way that I can achieve this requirement using any other tool.

This is what I was trying but this is not working.

```
  #!/bin/sh
   while inotifywait -e modify /var/log/dpkg.log; do   
      if tail -n1 /var/log/dpkg.log | grep installed; then
         // alert script    
       fi 
    done
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: It is a bit difficult to get what you are trying to achieve. It would be good, if you provided what you currently have scripted, so that we can help you with that including the regex pattern you want to use.

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 18.04, I'll edit the question with what I have tried. @pLumo

Comment: what you mean by it is not working? Could it be that `apt` writes multiple lines to `dpkg.log`, so `tail -n1` won't be enough here? As you don't know how many lines were added, you could maybe save the last state of the file and use `diff` ?

Comment: If there are changes to the file, the script starts and exits, but I want to monitor this continuously. How can I save the last state of the file?

Comment: strange that it exits. Your while loop should work well. Maybe you have "Exit on Error"  with `set -e` ?

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201366/a-bash-line-to-show-when-a-folders-contents-update) is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script using `diff` works:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# Save contents of dpkg.log
last_content=$(</var/log/dpkg.log)

# Loop inotifywait
while inotifywait -e modify /var/log/dpkg.log; do
    # Check diff between dpkg.log and last saved content.
    # Use grep to filter lines not interesting
    # save in a variabler called "diff".
    diff=$(diff /var/log/dpkg.log <(printf '%s' "$last_content") | grep '^<' | grep "status installed")

    # Check if the command to check "diff" succeeded ($? == 0)
    # if yes, run the alert:
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
        echo "$diff"
        notify-send "$(printf '%s' "$diff" | grep -Po "status installed \K.*") has been installed"
    fi

    # Save contents of dpkg.log
    last_content=$(</var/log/dpkg.log)
done
```

Instead of `notify-send`, you can of course use any other method for alert.

Comment: Thanks. can you please explain what this line is doing   diff=$(diff /var/log/dpkg.log <(printf '%s' "$last_content") | grep '^<' | grep "status installed"). I'm getting missing operand error diff: missing operand after 'test/dev/fd

Comment: ah yes? You copy-pasted it correctly? I don't get errors. Note, that this is run with `bash`.

Comment: yes, I used the same script but pointing to a file in local since I'm using arch linux and I used bash itself

Comment: But there is several places to replace the file .... Might be you're missing the space after `test` ?

Comment: You're right @pLumo, it is working now. Thanks a lot!