# Create bash script to auto put files in folder of the same name?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm very new to writing Linux scripts but I'm trying to do something rather complex. I'm trying to write a program that can read part of the file name of a file and put it into a folder named the same thing. For instance, if I put a file in the directory called "PO 123.PDF" it would automatically go into a "123" folder. From what I understand I can use inotify-tools to watch a folder for new files, but I'm not sure how to use the syntax. Would anybody know where to get started? Thank you!

Comment: Read `man bash;man -k inotify`. You'll use the `inotify` tools to monitor your directory for "`close`" events (`man close`), piping (`|`) the events to a `bash` fragment that will: Extract the filename, extract the directory name from the filename, make sure the directory exists, move (`man mv`) the file to the directory. This only seems complex due to your inexperience. It will get easier.

Comment: A script you run from time to time to move these files to a fitting folder would be quite a lot easier. Probably there is no strict need to have the files moved in real-time.

Comment: Is there a way i could make it run like once a minute? I think im gonna try and use the grep command to search for any files in the directory periodically that have .pdf in them instead.

Answer (score 2):

With `inotify-tools:`

```bsh
inotifywait -m . -e create |
  while read path action file;
  do
    d="${file##* }"
    d="${d%%.*}"
    mkdir -p "$d"
    mv "$file" "$d/" 2>/dev/null
  done
```

Run the above from within the directory containing your files.

---

In `bash`:

```bsh
while true
do
  for f in *
  do
    d="${f##* }"
    d="${d%%.*}"
    mkdir -p "$d"
    echo mv "$f" "$d/" 2>/dev/null
  done
  sleep 5
done
```

Save the above code in a file **one level above your files directory** and make it executable then run it from within the directory containing your files like so `bash ../ScriptFileName`. **Remove** `echo` when satisfied with results to do the actual file moving.

You can change the number of seconds after `sleep` from `sleep 5` to for example `sleep 60` to make the script run every minute instead of every 5 seconds.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1201375/968501) for extra information.